# <v-app> takes a lot more space than necessary (vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

I am creating a project in which I use "vuetify" and "vuetify-jsonschema-form". Basically, the problem is that `<v-app>` element takes 498 x 754.4 space, even if the child component `<v–content>` takes only what's necessary – 498 x 94. I have tried many suggestions – adding app property, etc. – but no progress, so I am posting here.

Code: (added both div's to indicate that I am using it in the middle of all the program (I need vuetify only in small part of the page))

```
...
</div>
<v-app id="vuetify_edit">
    <v-container>
        <v-form>
            <v-jsf v-model="editModel" :schema="editSchema" />
        </v-form>
    </v-container>
</v-app>
<div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `<v-app>` tags at the top – right inside `<template>` tags.

Although `<v-app` works in the middle of the app, it has some random height, width you can't really change.